# Eclipse does not support web projects or web file types after installing WTP. Am I installing it incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I currently have the latest version of Eclipse (Juno) and I have installed ADT with no problem. I have moved on to a web based project and I require support for JavaScript and HTML etc. I installed WTP through the update manager and you can see that all of the required packages appear to be installed:

[image: Image showing that all required packages appear to be installed]

However, within Eclipse there is very little evidence that anything has been installed. I have read in [this jsdt tutorial](http://kellicker.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/javascript-eclipse-ide-jsdt-getting-started/) that I should be able to create web projects such as "Static Web Project" and have text editting support for HTML and JavaScript. However, I see no web project options, HTML or JavaScript file options, no perspective options for HTML or JavaScript, and no support for editing html/javascript files.

Here you can see an html file I attempted to create. Notice the lack of syntax colouring:

[image: An Image showing no html editor support within my version of Eclipse]

Here you can also see all the project creation options that are available to me:

[image: An Image showing that there are no web based project types available in my version of Eclipse]

So how should I have installed WTP? Should I not have installed it thought Eclipse's software manager? I would like to do this without having to re-install Eclipse if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to exclusively occur in Windows 7. I managed to successfully install the desired software by right clicking on the Eclipse icon, selecting "Run As Administrator" and then re-installing all packages. I did not have to do this in Windows Vista.

If you are experiencing this problem and you are using Windows then follow these steps.

- Right click on the Eclipse icon and select **Run As Administrator**.
- Once you have opened your Workspace go to  **Help -> Install New Software**.
- Any installed packages that you installed when you did not **Run As Administrator** should now not appear to be installed. So install them again.
- Restart eclipse (normally if you wish) and your desired packages should be installed correctly.